# MySQL 5.0 - Return every nth row with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following table. I want to retrieve every 3rd row that has a price = 25. In other words, I want to to get the 3rd, 6th, 9th and so on rows where price = 25.

```
| id |  Product |  Price |
|------------------------|
| 1  |  Prod A  |  25    |
| 2  |  Prod B  |  25    |
| 3  |  Prod C  |  12    |
| 4  |  Prod D  |  10    |
| 5  |  Prod E  |  25    |
| 6  |  Prod F  |  11    |
| 7  |  Prod G  |  25    |
| 8  |  Prod H  |  25    |
| 9  |  Prod I  |  19    |
| 10 |  Prod J  |  25    |
--------------------------
```

Following the given table above, the result should be like this.

```
| id |  Product |  Price |
|------------------------|
| 5  |  Prod E  |  25    |
| 10 |  Prod J  |  25    |
--------------------------
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHERE MOD(id, 5) = 0` note that if some row have id = 0 it will also show. This solution isn't so efficient but works. In large tables you should experience some slowness

Comment: @EliasSoares It looks like it's just a coincidence that they're multiples of 5 in the example.

Comment: @EliasSoares Since the stated criteria is every 3rd row from `WHERE price = 25`. Why would that always be every 5th row in the original table?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get all the rows matching the price criteria. Use a user-defined variable to count row numbers. Then filter that on every third row number.

```
SELECT id, product, price
FROM (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS rownum, id, product, price
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE price = 25
        ORDER BY id
    ) AS x
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) AS vars
) AS y
WHERE rownum % 3 == 0
```

Comment: Will subquery be efficient if the volume of data is high?

Comment: Probably not. If you can do this in the client programming language that will probably be better.